# Jquery run functions for elements within a div

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make a overlay which fades in and has a div that rotates when you hover over a image. I've been able to get the overlay to work great but it comes up on all the images on the page, I only want it to show up on the image you hover over.

here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/G4cs9/

Here is my html

```
            </div><!-- end .image -->

            <div class="overlay"></div>
            <div class="button">
            </div>
        </div><!-- end .link -->

                <div class="link">

            <div class="image">

            </div><!-- end .image -->

            <div class="overlay"></div>
            <div class="button">

            </div>
        </div><!-- end .link -->
```

And my Jquery

```
$(".image").mouseover(function () {

$('.overlay').fadeTo(300, 0.5);

$('.button').show(200, function () {

    $(".button").addClass('box_rotate box_transition').delay(200).queue(function (next) {
        $(this).removeClass("box_rotate");
        next();
    });

});


});
```

and css

```
.link {
    height: 167px;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 10px;

}
.overlay {
    height: 167px;
    width: 250px;
    background-color: #000;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    display: none;
    z-index: 1;
}
.image {
    height: 167px;
    width: 250px;
    position: absolute;
     background-color: #ccc;
    top: 0px;
    -webkit-transition: all;
    -moz-transition: all;
    -ms-transition: all;
    -o-transition: all;
    transition: all;
}
.button {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    z-index: 20;
    display: none;
    left: 100px;
    top: 50px;
}
.box_rotate {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
    /* Chrome, Safari 3.1+ */
    -moz-transform: rotate(30deg);
    /* Firefox 3.5-15 */
    -ms-transform: rotate(30deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    -o-transform: rotate(30deg);
    /* Opera 10.50-12.00 */
    transform: rotate(30deg);
    /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera 12.50+ */
}
.box_transition {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    /* Chrome 1-25, Safari 3.2+ */
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    /* Firefox 4-15 */
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    /* Opera 10.50–12.00 */
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    /* Chrome 26, Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera 12.50+ */
}
```

Comment: So which part can we help with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$(".image").mouseover(function () {
    $(this).next('.overlay').fadeTo(300, 0.5);
    $(this).closest('div.link').find('.button').show(200, function () {
        $(this).addClass('box_rotate box_transition').delay(200).queue(function (next) {
            $(this).removeClass("box_rotate");
        });
    });
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/G4cs9/4/)**

You need to use `this` to refer to the specific element you're hovering over. So `$('.overlay').fadeTo(300, 0.5);` would trigger all overlay elements while `$(this).next('.overlay').fadeTo(300, 0.5);` will only trigger the one next to the image. The button is a similar case, just with a different series of jQuery functions needed.

Answer (score 0):

I have formatted the code. See if this helps:

```
$(".image").mouseover(function () {
$(this).next().fadeTo(300, 0.5);
$(this).siblings('.button').show(200, function () {
$(this).addClass('box_rotate box_transition').delay(200).queue(function (next) {
   $(this).removeClass("box_rotate");
    next();
});
});});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9ywBd/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".image").mouseover(function () {
    $(this).parent().find('.overlay').fadeTo(300, 0.5);
    $(this).parent().find('.button').show(200, function () {
        $(this).parent().find(".button").addClass('box_rotate box_transition').delay(200).queue(function (next) {
            $(this).removeClass("box_rotate");
            next();
        });
    }); 
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G4cs9/5/)